# How to read json output in SharePoint designer workflow?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am getting response in following JSON format

```
Affected_x0020_Program: {
results: [2]
0:  {
  __metadata: {
  id: "c6eb23d2-b6de-4f4b-a72c-052983faf36a"
  type: "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
}-
  Title: "Vijay"
}-
1:  {
  __metadata: {
  id: "0e2b317e-bfc9-4403-bff5-82721415982d"
  type: "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
}-
  Title: "Hole"
}-
-
}
```

How to read value of  `Affected_x0020_Program` in SharePoint designer workflow ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to add a "Call HTTP Web Service" action, which you might already did. Then in the "ResponseContent to" you have to assign it to a variable so that you can read from your json later.

Then you have to add a "Get an Item From a Dictionary" action where you will read from your responseContent variable.

It will show something like "Get *item by name or path* from *dictionary* (Output to *item*)

You will replace the *item by name or path* with the path of what you want from that json. In your case it would be enough if you type ProgramId.

Sorry if I explained things that you already know but you did not provide a bit more of detail. I hope this helps you. If not, please share more details

Comment: Thanks . I have already called HTTP web service and i am able to read values but problem is that when i am trying to read using 'ProgramId 'getting blank value .I think reason of blank value is 'ProgramId' contains 3 element so problem is here to read these 3 elements ? So how to read these element values in Sharepoint designer workflow?

Comment: Problem is how to read Multi select lookup value in SharePoint designer workflow using Get item ?

Comment: How to read follwoing JSON format Affected_x0020_Program: {
results: [2]
0:  {
__metadata: {
id: "2fbd598f-c7b5-4f01-baf8-7853aada5f0f"
type: "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
}-
Title: "Vijay"
}-
1:  {
__metadata: {
id: "7d6d2d33-27c8-4d50-846a-bca923dfdb04"
type: "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
}-
Title: "Hole"
}-
-
}

Comment: @user3760501 - Just quick question. Are you making sure that the Variable where you are placing the ResponseContent is of type DynamicValue?

Comment: @user3760501 - Try this: 
1. Add another "Get an item from a Dictionary". In the "get" part of it add "ProgramId/element", in the "from" part use the variable holding the ResponseContent, and in the output create a new variable of type "Dictionary" 
2. Add a "Count Items in dictionary" action. In the dictionary part of it add the newly created variable of type dictionary and in the output part of if create a new variable named count or whatever.

Comment: @user3760501 - 3. Add a "Loop n Times" (you have to create an index variable to loop through) and there you can use again another "Get Item from Dictionary", now you would specify something like:  element/([%Variable:index%])/__prefix

Comment: I am getting JSON in the following format  -Affected_x0020_Program: {
results: [2]
0:  {
__metadata: {
id: "c6eb23d2-b6de-4f4b-a72c-052983faf36a"
type: "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
}-
Title: "Vijay"
}-
1:  {
__metadata: {
id: "0e2b317e-bfc9-4403-bff5-82721415982d"
type: "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
}-
Title: "Hole"
}-
-
} Now how to get values "Vijay" And "Hole" ?

Comment: Your json does not seem to be well formatted. It should look like this:

{
  "Affected_x0020_Program": { 
    "results":
    [
     { "0":
       {
         "__metadata":
         {
           "id": "c6eb23d2-b6de-4f4b-a72c-052983faf36a",
           "type": "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
         }
         ,"Title": "Vijay"
       } 
     },
     { "1":
       {
         "__metadata":
         {
           "id": "0e2b317e-bfc9-4403-bff5-82721415982d",
            "type": "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
         },
         "Title": "Hole"
       } 
     }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Once you have it, try this and let me know: Affected_x0020_Program/results/([%Variable:index%])/Title

Comment: Hi I have tried with this but getting "Vijay" only not "Hole" because index need to add in for loop .Thanks for your reply .

Comment: You're welcome. And effectively, you would have to do it in a loop, but you know, once you have the value of title, you can make use of the Concat Action and that way you would get both values. Give it a try